# Changing the margin of a WPF Grid using animation

Tags: wpf, animation, grid, storyboard

Here's my XAML, so far when someone enter any image in my Window, the animation pops up correctly.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" From="1" To="1.2" AutoReverse="True"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" From="1" To="1.2" AutoReverse="True" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Now I'd like to create another storyboard, one that fires on `Image.MouseDown`, however this time the animation should change the margin of a Grid called `x:Name="container"`.

Can I access other controls properties inside a trigger? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 options here:

1. Create an `EventTrigger` for your Grid and set its [SourceName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.sourcename.aspx) property to Image name that fires MouseDown or it`s parent;
2. Add another `EventTrigger` directly to the Image and set [Storyboard.TargetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname.aspx) for animation to Grid`s name.